# How to use Rails 5.2 credentials in another .yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

I'm using the [Cloudinary gem](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#configuration) to allow a user to upload their avatar. In the docs, they offer a few ways to supply your api_key and api_secret, however I'm unable to get it work correctly with Rails credentials.

I've tried with the `cloudinary.yml`:

```
---
development:
  cloud_name: test_cloud
  api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key] %>
  api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
production:
  cloud_name: test_cloud
  api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key] %>
  api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: true
test:
  cloud_name: test_cloud
  api_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key] %>
  api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret] %>
  enhance_image_tag: true
  static_file_support: false
```

And I've also tried using a `cloudinary.rb` initializer:

```
Cloudinary.config do |config|
  config.cloud_name = "test_cloud"
  config.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key]
  config.api_secret = Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_secret]
  config.enhance_image_tag = true
  config.static_file_support = false
end
```

When I attempt to upload the image, I receive a 500 error `CloudinaryException (Must supply api_key)`. I know that the actual upload itself works because I hard-coded the values into the cloudinary.yml file to test it.

I've also tried using the `.fetch` function mentioned below, however I receive a `key not found: :api_secret (KeyError)`
How can I use Rails credentials within either of these files?

Comment: What exactly did not work? A protip is to use `Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary.fetch(:api_key)` instead of square brackets which raises an error if the key is not present instead of failing silently.

Comment: @max Apologies, should've included the actual error. I've updated my post.

Comment: The key error is good. It tells you that didn't actually setup the encrypted secrets properly and that the issue is there and not really related to Cloudinary at all. https://medium.com/@kirill_shevch/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc

Comment: That's strange, because if I run something like `Rails.application.credentials.cloudinary[:api_key]` in my rails console, it returns the correct value?

Comment: Is the console running in the same environment/machine?

Comment: Yes I'm running all this locally in the same terminal session

Comment: Weird, do you get the same behavior for any other keys from the credentials?

Comment: Oh jeez, I just opened up my credentials to double check the keys, and the one that was hanging up was actually called `secret` instead of `api_secret`. Doh! Thanks for rubber ducking that with me!

Comment: No worries. Doing something exactly like this is how I learned to always use `.fetch`.